# Rails ajax error while creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello guys I want use ajax in my rails application :
Here is my routes.rb file

```
ExampleAjax::Application.routes.draw do
   root 'users#index'
    resources :users
end
```

my controller file

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new
  end
 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.js   {}
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private 
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:fname)
end
end
```

My view files
index.html.erb

```
<b>Users</b>

<ul id="users">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render user %>
<% end %>
</ul>

<br>

<%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :fname %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :fname %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb

```
<%=form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f|%>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :fname %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :fname %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :lname %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :lname %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

_user.html.erb

```
<li><%= user.fname %></li>
```

_create.js.erb

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>").appendTo("#users");
```

And my problem is when I click create user 
I got the following error in console

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: what do your logs say when you get the error?

Comment: ActionView::MissingTemplate(Missing template users/create,application/create with {:locale=>[:en]...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is hitting this block:

```
format.js   {}
```

Which has nothing defined in it, so your app will try to do what it normally does, ie. render the view for the action you are in.

You are in a create action, and your format is js, so it will try to render `create.js.erb`.

You should rename your `_create.js.erb` to remove the underscore.

Comment: What does escape_javascript mean

Comment: @Goutam http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax**

> I want use ajax in my rails application

To give you some info about [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), it's basically integrated in your application already:

> Ajax is a group of interrelated web development techniques used on the
>   client-side to create asynchronous web applications

It's basically a way to send an `asynchronous` request to your web app (through javascript). Asynchronous essentially means you're sending requests out of scope of the typical HTTP "synchronous" request structure

[`HTTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) works by responding to requests. Each click you perform is sending a request to your server, which responds with data. `Synchronous` requests are ones you perform in order, whereas asynchronous "ajax" ones are sent independently

---

**Code**

Your problem is you don't have a `create.js.erb` file:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html #-> action.html.erb
    format.js #-> action.js.erb
end
```

Unless you call some other methods in this block (such as `render nothing`), Rails will look for your `action.js.erb` file in your `views` directory

---

**Rails**

Rails handles all requests equally, and determines if it's an `ajax` request using the [ActionDispatch::Http::MimeNegotiation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/MimeNegotiation.html) class

This means you don't have to do anything "special" to use Ajax -- just send the requests to your routes, and handle them in the backend using `respond_to do |format|`